# An extra Father's Day

Tags: situation

I recently celebrated my 2nd Father's Day, yet my only child hasn't even had a first birthday yet.

How is this possible?

Clarifications: I live in the US and in my family you only celebrate Father's Day after your child has been born.

Comment: Why is it on hold? It's a nice question.It seems that PSE is someones property.

Comment: Who says you have to be a father to celebrate Father's Day?

Comment: @Emrakul - My understanding is that it is normal for the situation tag to invite many plausible answers, but there should be only one answer that is completely satisfying, which (I thought) I accomplished.

Comment: @TTT I'd originally put your question on hold because I'm not sure it has enough detail to sufficiently limit possible objectively correct answers. For example, many of [the highest voted situation questions](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bsituation%5d%20closed%3ano) contain multiple extended paragraphs of detail; this puzzle is only a single sentence. Is it possible to expand it to add more detail without giving it away?

Comment: @Emrakul - Probably. I was worried it was too easy, and so I didn't want to guide the solver away from other trains of thought. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Emrakul - shot taken. :)

Comment: @TTT It's in the reopen votes queue!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because

> Your child was born on June 20th.
>  Last year (2015), Father's Day was June 21st, so you celebrated it the day after your child was born.
>  Since 2016 is a leap year, Father's Day was on the 19th, not the 20th, so you celebrated Father's Day the second time before your child turned 1.

Comment: I figured this would be pretty easy, but sometimes you just need a simple puzzle. Plus this one happens to be true, which makes it kind of cool. She was actually born on Father's Day last year (June 21st). It works for both June 20 and June 21 though. (Arguably June 20 is slightly better because you get 2 full 24-hour Father's days.) She turns 1 tomorrow.

Answer (score 5):

Because you've

> moved another country recently. The father's day is being celebrated at different dates per country. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father%27s_Day

Answer (score 4):

I think:

> Some people celebrate fathers day when the woman is pregnant because technically you are a father at that point. So if the woman was 2 months pregnant and during first fathers day then the baby would be born 7 months after fathers day so you could celebrate the second fathers day when child is 5 months old.

Answer (score 1):

I think:

> You had a pair of twin just born not long ago or before their 1st birthday?

Comment: This doesn't account for celebrating two Father's Days. It would account for celebrating one Father's Day twice as hard though!

Answer (score 0):

It's because...

> Your child was born on February 29th in a leap year, so the first birthday only comes after four years.

Comment: This answer will work one year from now, but currently only 1 Father's Day has occurred since Feb 29, 2016.